# mongodb - find records with at least 3 populated arrays

Tags: mongodb

My records each have the following attributes of type Array:

```
alpha, beta, gamma, delta, epsilon, zeta
```

I know I can find records that have at least one component in an array, like this:

```js
db.accommodations.find({'alpha.1': {$exists: true}})
```

I want to be able to find records that have at least one component in at least 3 arrays. For example, this record could be found:

```js
alpha = []
beta = [1, 1, 1]
gamma = []
delta = [1, 1]
epsilon = []
zeta = [1]
```

But this could not:

```js
alpha = []
beta = [1, 1, 1]
gamma = []
delta = [1, 1]
epsilon = []
zeta = []
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query

- puts them in a parent array
- filter them and keep only those that have `$size>=1`
  (`$size` is more general, if you only care for at least 1, you can also do `$ne` with `[]`)
- if the result of the filter has `$size>=3` document passes

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62485bebf7e3c64c6511e161)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": 
   {"$expr": 
     {"$gte": 
       [{"$size": 
           {"$filter": 
             {"input": 
               ["$alpha", "$beta", "$gamma", "$delta", "$epsilon", "$zeta"],
              "cond": {"$gte": [{"$size": "$$this"}, 1]}}}},
        3]}}}])
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
"$match": {
  "$expr": {
    "$gte": [
      {
        $sum: [
          {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $eq: [
                  "$alpha",
                  []
                ]
              },
              "then": 0,
              "else": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $eq: [
                  "$beta",
                  []
                ]
              },
              "then": 0,
              "else": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $eq: [
                  "$gamma",
                  []
                ]
              },
              "then": 0,
              "else": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $eq: [
                  "$delta",
                  []
                ]
              },
              "then": 0,
              "else": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $eq: [
                  "$epsilon",
                  []
                ]
              },
              "then": 0,
              "else": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $eq: [
                  "$zeta",
                  []
                ]
              },
              "then": 0,
              "else": 1
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      3
     ]
    }
  }
 }
])
```

Explained:

$match  if the sum() on non empty arrays is >=3
where empty=0 and non-empty=1

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e-vbzay_Pp-)